# XAML Islands, Always get an error trying to publish the WPF Project. More people having the same issue?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp-xaml, xaml-islands

I am trying to run the WPF XAML Islands example commited by Microsoft at https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Islands-Samples. Every time I publish the app and try to execute the project in at any windows 10 machine (yes i have confirm that have the same revision) i get the same error:

Application: WPF_XAMLIslands_v1.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.700.20.36602
.NET Core Version: 3.1.7
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Any idea in this matter??? The revision of windows 10 I am using is 2004

Comment: looks like a framework error to me. make sure you've installed the correct SDK

Comment: i think about that also, did a reinstall to the latest windows sdk available and no luck, also if i use the release /bin .exe file in the development machine it works, but not if you try in other machines.

Comment: and .NET CORE ?

Answer (score 2):

i found the issue, it was the packaging manifest. It didn't have define the target revision. After define my target device family everything start working

...

...